# Use Get-Content within Invoke-SQLCmd

Tags: sql, powershell

Is it possible to load a list of IDs from a text file within a SQL cmd in a powershell script?
Basically, I have a text file with a list of IDs (they already have the single quotes and commas around each one) and I want to use this list in the Where clause of my SQL Query:

```
$File="C:\IDList.txt" Invoke-SQLCmd -Query "Update Table Set
Column='ID'  where numberID IN ( Get-Content $File)"
-ServerNameInstance servername\instance -Username enduser -Password
password
```

I'm not sure how to type this out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the basics of how [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) works and since you using an already formatted string, this might just be a matter of using a sub-expression. That will allow the text from the file to expand inside the string properly.

```
Invoke-SQLCmd -Query "Update Table Set Column='ID'  where numberID IN ($(Get-Content $File))" -ServerNameInstance servername\instance -Username enduser -Password password
```

This is of course assuming you text file contains one line like this:

```
"id2343","id3344","id8853",....
```

Comment: Hey Matt, Thanks for the Reply! yes that was it! I setup a new parameter as $IDList = Get-Content $File then in the WHERE clause i just put the new parameter after the IN. Thanks for the help!
I ran into a small complication regarding the SQL login(Can't seem to run it with user login, only admin login...not sure where to grant that access), but i'll post a new question if i have to.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help elsewhere and they were able to add a step in my query to do a rollback tran if the @@Rowcount <> the ID count in the text file list. Here's what the script looks like now.

```
$IDList = (get-content $file) -join ",";
$ExpectedUpdateCount = YOUR_NUMBER;
$UpdateQuery = @"
begin transaction
update table set column='ID' where numberid in ($IDList)
if @@ROWCOUNT <> $ExpectedUpdateCount
begin
    rollback transaction
end
else
begin
    commit transaction
end
"@;
invoke-sqlcmd -query $UpdateQuery -serverinstance servername\instance
-username enduser -password password;
```